# Putting linear-gradient over an image

Tags: html, css, image

How exactly would I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/4f2646gx/2/

What I want to do is place the linear gradient lines over the image.

What it looks like now:

[image]

**The end result should look like this:**

[image]

```
<style>
  #img1 {
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: circle(85px at center);
    top: 54%;
    left: 72%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  #img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 72%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

</style>

<div style="width: 260px; height: 194px; cursor: pointer;background-color: #000000 ;background-image: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 0, transparent  83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px,transparent 260px ); border: 3px solid #0059dd;">

  <div style="position:relative; width:180px; height:180px">
    <img id="img1" width="170" height="113" src="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg">
    <img id="img2" width="180" height="180" src="https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) is your friend. However, the gradient is the background of the container div. You'll need to place it in another element and move that element above the images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing gradient over image, and before the SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108325/placing-gradient-over-image-and-before-the-svg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put all of it in one container, use absolute positioning to layer the elements.  Also your background-color style of the gradient element needs to be transparent, otherwise you've got a black box with lines over your image and you can't see it.  In this example, you'll also notice that border is moved to the top level container.

```css
#container {
    background-color: black;
    position:relative; 
    width:260px;
    height:194px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 3px solid #0059dd;
}

#img1,#img2 {
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#img1 {
    clip-path: circle(85px at center);
}
  
#grad {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px; 
    height: 194px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent; 
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 0, transparent  83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px,transparent 260px ); 
   
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id="img1" width="170" height="113" src="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg">
    <img id="img2" width="180" height="180" src="https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png">
    <div id="grad"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I remove the image shadow from when you mouse click on it? https://i.imgur.com/9xjfh6b.png

Comment: i don't see a shadow in the example i provided.

Comment: Right click on the image repeatedly.

Comment: that's not a shadow, thats where you've simply 'selected' the image in the browser by double clicking it.  Similar to selecting text in a browser you can select other elements.

Comment: Can I remove that?

Comment: Try this: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-css3-userint-19990916#user-select

Comment: @coding4567 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: His code below yours, when you click on it, nothing shows.

Comment: Well I can't help you with that.  That's his code. :) Unless you're talking about the selection highlight which in that case it does.  I just opened his JSBin, double clicked it and it shows up.

Comment: I just added the user-select property to the css for the images. In the snippet above. Re-run it and see if that does what you need.

Comment: that screen snapshot is not my snippet. Snippets have a white background.  when I run the snippet, and click all over it, it's not highlighted.

Comment: Do you recommend doing it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/6rwsn2o0/ Can you implement what @Creaforge put in his code into yours? What's your opinion about what he did with the code?

Comment: You could certainly do it that way. There's always more than one way to accomplish something. as far as what the other use did with the pseudo class. Yes thats great as well.  However this conversation is really starting to expand outside of the scope of the original question.  You have your solutions. It's not necessary for me to alter my code adding elements from other answers. If you want to merge the two answers, you're more than welcome to in your own code.  Have a good evening. signing off.

Comment: Can you show me how I can your code to this audio button? https://jsfiddle.net/7h8jsvch/

Comment: Hey man, this is not a free code writing service. If you need help with a specific problem start a new question and present the code that you’ve attempted to use and explain where your hang ups are.

Comment: Would you be able to help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108325/placeing-linear-gradient-over-image-and-before-the-svg

Answer (score 1):

To avoid adding any unnecessary markup, you can add a pseudo-element to your container div. [Forked JSBin.](https://jsfiddle.net/7nrnuofk/1/)

```
<style>  
  #img1, #img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 72%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  #img1 {
    clip-path: circle(85px at center);
  }
  .circle-gradient {
    width: 260px;
    height: 194px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 3px solid #0059dd;
    position: relative;
  }

  .circle-gradient:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 0, transparent  83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px,transparent 260px );
  }

</style>

<div class="circle-gradient">
  <div style="position:relative; width:180px; height:180px">
    <img id="img1" width="170" height="113" src="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg">
    <img id="img2" width="180" height="180" src="https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How come, on the code above yours, when you right click on it, this appears. https://i.imgur.com/9xjfh6b.png But on your code, that doesn't appear when you click on the image. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Because CSS FTW, you can use the `background` property to stack multiple images & gradients.

In this code snippet, `background-size` references each background applied : the last value (`120px 120px`) sets the size of the sky image.

The good news is that it is supported since IE9!

```css
div{
  background:
    linear-gradient( to right,transparent 0, transparent  83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px,transparent 260px ),
    url("https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png") no-repeat center,
    url("https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: auto, auto, 120px 120px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 194px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: How do I get the top code, your code, to look like the bottom code? https://jsfiddle.net/40mzkn1m/1/